# Deploying a distributed .net system with multiple solutions

Tags: .net, git, tfs, projects-and-solutions, distributed

We have a distributed .net system which consists of several solutions, each with different configuration and deployment needs. Currently all the code is in one TFS project and each solution has its own build. These are configured to trigger for changes in that solutions source control folder.

We are moving to Team City, Git and rake (due to ease of branching and license costs) and so are reviewing the whole build process and have been unable to find good information on this. The issues we are struggling to resolve are:

1. Should we have separate builds or one large build? All the solutions need to be built and deployed for the system to function, but it is nice to have small builds as they are quick and easier to debug. Some solutions are more "stand alone" than others. Our current practice is mostly just to queue all the builds when we want to deploy to test or production environment, but sometimes we just queue an individual solution if that is all that has changed.
2. Should we store all the solutions in one repository or should we have a repository for each one? We use some shared projects and dlls, how would these work with separate repositories?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of different ways to store repositories, perform builds and deploy instances. And many from them are right. From my practice it is not important what technique you use and what tool to make builds and deployment. So it is important to raise questions that affect these processes:

- to prevent messing of the solutions/projects that can be separated (as stand alone).
  *If a project is shared between few solutions, then it would be better to create a separate repository for it. And just add relations from dependent solutions/projects to this;*
- to prevent problems during generation of different builds for different purposes (Configuration Management in other words). *You can adjust TeamCity for this (mostly for build and deploy automation after each 'commit' or time-based schedule), or use some simple but powerful utility like NAnt with predefined configurations.*

So I see no reason to make one large build (only on release may be), but separate builds would be easier to use (for QA, and developers that work on some part only). The second issue is a time. For example, to make full build with all the projects in one solution it takes about 10 minutes on quad cpu 8gb ram, but to make a build with Accounting part or Enrollment part only it takes 1 minute - it does matter for me. Just try to imagine this process, draw on a piece of paper, and it become clear - what to do, and why do.

All opinion is based on my practice only, in well successful projects that experiencing changes every day/night and have dozens of configurations (your builds).

Comment: I don't fully understand your answer. What exactly is "messing of the solutions/projects"? Why would you want to create a separate repository for a shared project? We have all our solutions in folders under one repository and use relative paths to share the project (add existing project in visual studio). Are you suggesting we branch the project into all our solutions (this has merge overhead)? The only reason we are considering one large build is that most of the builds are dependent on each other.

Comment: messing of the solutions/projects - means that too large solution makes some confusion for most of people who work with it (devs, qa, code reviewers). and it is harder to split functionality if this will be required (for ex. your client wants to have only couple of features), but your developers added excessive dependency between projects (sometimes it happening). when a solution is splitted - it is easier to maintain each part separately

Comment: About repositories. When you have all your solutions in one repository - it makes some SourceControl commands harder to use: Branch, Merge, ...

Comment: About "add existing project in visual studio". If a shared project is "stand alone" and might be used like a component, I would not include this project to a solution, but would add as a reference. Reasons: 1) referenced dll could be debugged too with existance of .pdb files and correct source location (stored in .pdb after each compilation). 2) Each additional project in "Solution Explorer"-listing adds some problems with Visual Studio performance. Less projects + less members = better response time of VS when it sometimes freezes and thinking about something

Comment: So my opinion can be expressed in one phrase: Simplifying the methods - 
simplifies life. "I don't fully understand your answer." - sorry, English is not my native language ;)